# Maple not displaying graph

Tags: graph-theory, maple

Maple is only producing a description of a graph, e.g.

C := Graph 9: an undirected unweighted graph with 66 vertices and 219 edge(s),

rather than displaying the graph. Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how Maple's GraphTheory package is designed to work.
In order to show a graph and its structure you need to use "DrawGraph(C);"

Here's an example with a smaller graph:
[image: Maple's Petersen Graph]

For more information about different options use Maple's help for DrawGraph.